# Most secure way to deny direct access to my folders in a server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I've been looking for the answer before asking you, but I haven't found the exact case I'm in.

My website has a lot of folders: /js, /css, /img... and I want to deny people accessing them. I think the best for me could be a redirection to my index, and I've made a first approach by typing this in my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /js http://my.awesome.website/
```

But of course, every javascript I'm calling isn't loading because the redirection. My question is: there's a way to just redirect the access but keep calling my JS, imgs and so? or should I forget that solution and give a 403 Error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you block people from accessing those files then they will not be able to view your website. If the JavaScript, CSS and image files are not accessible then people will not be able to properly browser your website. The best you could possible try is to prevent hotlink. Also "BEST way" is subjective to multiple right answers which is primarily opinion-based and off-topic in this website.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Prix . I explain my definition of "Best way" in the message: "there's a way to just redirect the access but keep calling my JS, imgs and so? or should I forget that solution and give a 403 Error?" That's binary; if the first is possible, that's the way. If not, the other it's the best.

Comment: You better define it in your title as well, unless you want it closed as off-topic. No its not binary, both are bad, if not wrong as well, the best you could do is prevent hotlink **(which is not a bullet-proof solution against having your resources viewed or stolen in any case and is easily by passed)** unless those resources are not needed at all by any of your accessed pages which then you could just completely deny access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the solution you search for is disabling [directory listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) ?

Blocking access to any of the directories is pointless if there is content in them the browser needs to run your site. Regardless of you using 301 or 403, 404, 500 or any other http status code: the browser will never ever have access to any file in that directory and you will have to live without javascripts, images, css, ...

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you very much!